# jstree hide child checkboxes and only show parent checkboxes

Tags: checkbox, jstree

Is it possible to do this in CSS - I have tried a couple of things below which do not quite work. Basically I need to display checkboxes at the Parent level and hide all children, I have tried the following:

```
    .jstree-children > .jstree li.jstree-open >a.jstree-anchor >  i.jstree-checkbox { display:none;  }

    .jstree li.jstree-open   > a.jstree-anchor >  i.jstree-checkbox { display:none;  }
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do it this way:

1. Add `"state":{ "checkbox_disabled": true }` to the children
2. Add this to your css: `.jstree-anchor > .jstree-checkbox-disabled { display: none; }`

Check fiddle: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/bps96btu/)

Comment: cheers - could not quite get it working using the state - but did a similar thing with the ID and then used similar CSS to hide it.

Comment: Glad you did it! If my answer helped you please accept it.

Comment: On jstree 3.3.15 th selector must be .jstree-anchor.jstree-disabled > .jstree-checkbox